# Redirect all url with # from HashRouter to BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redirect, react-router

I changed HashRouter to BrowserRouter and now I would like to redirect all urls to remove # from them. (Url are in e.g. mailing - so I have to do it).

I found a similar topic to this, but none of the solutions there works for me.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Index extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
    <Redirect from='/#/bus/:category' to '/bus/:category' />
    <Route exact path='/bus/:category' component={BusCategory} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

It's redirecting only to HomePage.

Next solution also not working:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Index extends Component {

    render() {


 const history = useHistory()

  if (location.hash.startsWith('#/')) {
    history.push(location.hash.replace('#', '')) // or history.replace
  }

        return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
    <Route exact path='/bus/:category' component={BusCategory} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

and the last one also nothning :(

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Index extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
    <Route exact path='/bus/:category' component={BusCategory} />
    <Route path={"/bus/:category"} render={({ location }) => <Redirect strict to={location.hash.replace('#', '')} />} />

  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

I've probably already tried all the options, if anyone can help me I'll be extremely grateful.

// EDIT

now everything works, except the HomePage...

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Index extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
 <Route path={"/bus/:category"} render={({ location }) => <Redirect strict to={location.hash.replace('#', '')} />} />
    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
    <Route exact path='/bus/:category' component={BusCategory} />

  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

Comment: 1. Some of the urls are used in mailing to clients, which is why I need to create these redirects. Eg. /#/bus/:category/car1 I would like to be automatically redirected to /bus/:category/car1, not to the home page. 2. Of course it's a mistake. I am already improving, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Index = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const location = useLocation()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.hash) {
      history.replace(location.hash.replace('#', ''))
    }
  }, [history, location.hash, location.pathname])
  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path={'/'} render={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/bus/:category"
        render={({ match: { params } }) => <div>{params.category}</div>}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Index />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Your previous code didn't work because `<Index />` component was **not the child** of `BrowserRouter` component, because of which the `location`, as well as `history`, would be `undefined`.

Now if you try to visit `localhost:3000/#/bus/car` it would redirect to `localhost:3000/bus/car`.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Why do you have to do a redirect at all? If I understand you correctly, you only used the BrowserRouter instead of the HashRouter. Exchanged, so to speak. This automatically eliminates the # and the pages "/#/bus/:category" simply no longer exist.
2. Is the line `<Redirect from='/#/bus/:category' to '/bus/category' />` really correct? When I read this, it looks to me like you are referring to the URL "/bus/category". But actually you want something like "/bus/cars".